# How do I set select options using JSON data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have an array of select boxes, with a unique id like this.

```
 <select class="taskcompleted" id="c392018">
 <option value="No">No</option>
 <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
 </select>
```

I have a JSON in the format

```
  {"id":"c392018","value":"Yes"}
```

I am using the following Javascript to set the selected value

```
   $.getJSON('getstatus.php') //place correct script URL
    .done(function(response) {
        $.each(response, function(key) {
            var SelectObj = response[key];
            console.log(SelectObj['value']);
            jQuery('#' + SelectObj['id']).val(SelectObj['value']).attr('selected', true);
            });
        });
```

This is not selecting the value of "Yes". How can I do this?

Comment: Have you tried using `.prop()` instead of `.attr()`?

Comment: If you need to access the keys directly by name, there's no reason for a `$.each`. Seems like you just want `jQuery('#' + response.id).val(response.value).attr('selected', true);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to use .val() to set the selected option using the value from your object:

**So where you have:**

```
jQuery('#' + SelectObj['id']).val(SelectObj['value']).attr('selected', true);
```

**Should be:**

```
jQuery('#' + SelectObj['id']).val(SelectObj['value']);
```

**See the snippet example below:**

Also if you really want the selected property on the item, you should use:

```
.prop("selected", "selected");
```

```js
var SelectObj = {"id":"c392018","value":"Yes"};
jQuery('#' + SelectObj['id']).val(SelectObj['value']).prop('selected','selected');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="taskcompleted" id="c392018">
   <option value="No">No</option>
   <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you don't really need jQuery here.

```
var select = document.getElementById(SelectObj.id);
select.value = SelectObj.value;
```

Comment: Don't use `#` when calling `getElementById`.

Comment: You don't need to use `forEach`. You can just do `select.value = SelectObj.value`.

Comment: @Barmar yeah I checked, I don't really need any iterations

Comment: @Balmar thanks I updated the answer. Still don't understand why the guy uses jQuery here

Comment: Maybe because he's using jQuery throughout his application, and it's his preferred style. `$(blah)` is easier to type than `document.getElementById(blah)`.